# How to close sequence gaps in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a Turtle table.  When I run

```
SELECT * FROM Turtle ORDER BY Sort
```

I get this:

```
Id | Name | Sort
2    Leo    1
3    Raph   2
4    Don    5
1    Mike   7
```

What is the easiest way to close the gaps between Raph and Don, and between Don and Mike, so that the table looks like this?

```
Id | Name | Sort
2    Leo    1
3    Raph   2
4    Don    3
1    Mike   4
```

This should work no matter how many turtles are in the table, and no matter how many gaps there are or how long each gap is.

Comment: Sounds a lot like homework to me. Take a look at ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Thanks, Sean.  I ran into a much more complex problem like this and was able to find an answer, but thought I'd distill the question and answer for anyone else with the same problem.  See my answer below, which does indeed use ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @marc_s I don't think the OP is worried about the identity. This is another column, sort order and not having gaps in a column like that does make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the update just using a CTE with the row_number(), and then just update the CTE:

```
;with CTE as (
  select *, row_number () over (order by Sort) as RN
  from Turtle
)

update CTE
set Sort = RN
```

Comment: Thanks, @JamesZ!  This is really good.  I still have a lot to learn about SQL, and this is my first introduction to CTEs.  I didn't realize that you could update a CTE directly.  Very cool!  I'm going to start using these right away.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort) AS Sort FROM Turtle
```

Comment: Thanks, Faisal.  I did use something like this in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35022336/4888725).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer I came up with:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Sort = t2.Sort
FROM Turtle AS t,
(SELECT Id, Sort = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort) FROM Turtle) as t2
WHERE t.Id = t2.Id
```

We can select the Turtle table as t2, ordering the turtles by the Sort column, but assigning the ROW_NUMBER() to the Sort column. We can then use the new value in t2.Sort to update each row in the Turtle table where the Ids match.

**Edit (based on Juan Carlos Oropeza's feedback):**

Here is the code using an explicit JOIN instead.

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Sort = t2.Sort
FROM Turtle AS t
JOIN (SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort) AS Sort FROM Turtle) AS t2 ON t.Id = t2.Id
```

Comment: Looks like Sean point you on the right direction. Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: You can do this without joining back to the table, just create a CTE with the row_number() and update it

Comment: +1000 to what @JamesZ says. There is no need to run two separate queries against the same table.

Comment: Thanks, @JuanCarlosOropeza. I think I get what you mean. Take a look at my edit, and let me know if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: @JamesZ and SeanLange, I'm not sure how I would use a CTE to get the row_number() *without* a select query. Could you clarify? If you want to put it in another answer and explain how it cuts down on the number of queries, I'd be happy to mark yours as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what they mean by using a cte in an update.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort) NewSort 
    FROM Turtle
)
UPDATE cte SET Sort = NewSort
```